# How do I get rid of the "gaps" in my multi-monitor setup?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have a multiple monitor setup with my laptop and three external screens on Windows 7, like so:

[image: display-properties]

Is there any way to allow me to move directly from monitor 1 to monitor 2 or 4, instead of having to go through monitor 3?

Comment: If you are using Windows built in multimonitor tools, then I dont believe so.  You could set the resolution of monitor 1 and 3 to the same size, but you probably wouldnt want to do that.

Comment: Monitors 1 and 3 are different physical sizes so their resolutions never quite match up. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, there is no way to move across a gap.  Consider a different layout.

**Option 1: Choose a side**

Move monitor 1 against 2 or 4

**Option 2: 3 On Top**

- Move 3 above 2 and 4
- Move in 2 and 4 against monitor 1
- (Optional) Move up monitor 1 to align top edges of 1, 2, and 4.

**Option 3: Alternate physical layout**

Rearrange the monitors physically in a layout which would minimize gaps.

Comment: I don't really like any of those options. I'm pretty happy with the monitor setup as it is now. I've been using Ultramon's hotkeys to move the mouse to next/previous monitors, so I guess that will have to do. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same question, and solved it using this app https://cursr.app/

Comment: Link only answers tend to be removed, see: https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1192924)